# Passing argument to a defined function so they accessible to sys.argv in python3

Tags: python-3.x, parameter-passing, user-defined-functions

I have a program (`temp.py`) in python3 that reads the temperature at sensors in a solar panel. I also have a program (`stepper.py`) that I use to control a stepper motor. The program `stepper.py` uses `sys.argv` to evaluate arguments and determine how far and how quickly the motor should turn. I now want to call `stepper.py` from `temp.py` to combine the functionality of the two programs. However, when I call `stepper.py` from `temp.py` the arguments are not passed in a way that `sys.argv` can use them. I have written a short script to illustrate my problem:

```
import sys  
y=5  
z=2  
def called(a,b): 
    print(str(sys.argv))  
    print(len(sys.argv[1:]))  
    global p,q  
    p=a*b  
    q=a+b

called(y,z)  
print(p,q)
```

This script returns the following:

```
['/home/pi/calling.py']  
0  
10 0
```

In other words, although the calculation of the arguments has been completed, `sys.argv` is saying that no arguments have been passed and merely shows `argv[0]` which is the program's name. I understand why this occurs but is there any way that I can get `sys.argv` to "see" the arguments?

Comment: Do you call your code in stepper.py using an import or subprocess?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of a way to manually fill argv, but that doesn't really seem like the best way of achieving your goal here to me. You're trying to call a python function in one module from another, so you should do that using Python's normal importing and function call mechanisms, not by repurposing argv, which is designed to handle command line arguments. Usig python's [`if __name__ == "__main__"`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html) construction, you can still pass command line arguments through to the function.

If you haven't already, this will require wrapping up the code you have in your modules into functions with well-defined arguments. Here's an example of the approach I'm describing:

```
# stepper.py
import sys

def turn_motor(rotations, speed=1):
    """Turns the stepper motor"""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Code in this block will run when stepper.py is invoked from the command line
    turn_motor(rotations=sys.argv[1], speed=sys.argv[2])
```

and in your other file

```
# temp.py
import sys
from stepper import turn_motor

def detect_temp():
    """Returns the current temperature"""


def turn_when_hot(threshold):
    """Turns stepper motor when temperature above given threshold"""
    temperature = detect_temp()
    if temperature > threshold:
        # Calls the turn_motor function directly with whatever arguments
        # you like, without having to mess with sys.argv
        turn_motor(revolutions=3, speed=1.2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    turn_when_hot(sys.argv[1])
```

So you could call stepper.py from the command line with arguments for turns and speed, or you could call temp.py with an argument for a temperature threshold, and it would call `stepper.turn_motor` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the equivalent fixed code with notes below:

```
def called(a, b):
    return a*b, a+b

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    import sys

    y=5
    z=2
    print(str(sys.argv))
    print(len(sys.argv[1:]))
    p, q = called(y, z)
    print(p, q)
```

As TroyHurts wrote, separate the core functionality to the functions, and the body to the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block.

Then you will be able to `import stepper` in your `temp.py`. If you need `sys.argv` in `temp.py`, import the `sys` in the `temp.py`.

The `import sys` in `stepper.py` can even be moved to the `if` block if it is not used in the function definitions.

The functions (in `stepper.py`) should get all inputs as function arguments. They should return everything through the `return` statement.

Never use `global`.

The `called` is not a nice identifier. Choose better one. ;)